# How to set the source IP for the routing in nmtui?

Tags: routing

How to set the source (src address) IP for a routing entry in nmtui? On Centos 7.

from /usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.49.37/sysconfig.txt, the interface config file can have the following line too:

```
SRCADDR=use the specified source address for outgoing packets
```

**Q:** But how to do the same with the menu-based nmtui?

Comment: the people who downvote: do they even know what is the source setting at routing? :)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how was the result different to what you expected.  Please [edit] your question to be as specific as you can.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?